# How do you replace < and > (but not what's between them) with PHP RegExp?

Tags: php, regex

I've found dozens of functions that can remove whole HTML tags with the preg_replace() function, but I need to remove only the html brackets < and > (leaving anything inside them put). What regexp would accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need a regular expression at all? This sounds like a simple string replace, to replace "<" and ">" with an empty string "".

Comment: Yeah it can be done with simple str_replace function (no need for regEx)

Comment: Are the `<>` characters encoded entities by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net). It replaces HTML reserved characters with escape sequences. This way the characters are displayed in the browser but aren't harmful at all.

This probably is what you want - show exactly the text the client typed in, but make it harmless.

PS: If you really do need a regex to remove tag-brackets, here you go: `$text = preg_replace('/[<>]/', '', $text)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
str_replace(array("<", ">", "&lt;", "&gt;"), "", $text);
```

..?

Comment: I tried using str_replace. I was hoping there was a regexp that could do the trick.

Comment: @MarathonStudios how about replacing html escaped chars too? (edited answer)

Comment: @MarathonStudios Why would you prefer a regexp over a simple str_replace? The latter is vastly more efficient.